# PDF Tm operator

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to highlight text in a PDF document but I found a Tm operator with the following operands:

```
0 7.98 -7.98 0 90.8898 715.4183 Tm
```

The Tm operator is supposed to replace the text matrix and the text line matrix solely on its operands. 
According to the Pdf Reference, the following operations can be done:

- Translations [1 0 0 1 tx ty]
- Scaling [sx 0 0 sy 0 0]
- Rotation [cos(angle) sin(angle) -sin(angle) cos(angle) 0 0]
- Skew [1 tan(alpha) tan(beta) 1 0 0]

The format of the operands doesn't match any of the above transformations, which led to the following questions.

- What is the previously mentioned text matrix supposed to do?
- How would a several transformations look like? For example Scaling and rotation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *What is the previously mentioned text matrix supposed to do?*

Your matrix

```
0 7.98 -7.98 0 90.8898 715.4183
```

(which is the PDF short form for

```
⌈  0        7.98    0 ⌉
| -7.98     0       0 |
⌊ 90.8898 715.4183  1 ⌋
```

and unfortunately it is difficult to draw big brackets indeed)

is a combination of a 90° rotation, a scaling by 7.98, and a translation operation by 90.8898, 715.4183. I'll approximate those numbers in the following, 7.98 ≅8, 90.8898 ≅ 91, and 715.4183 ≅ 715:

```
⌈  0   8  0 ⌉   ⌈  0  8  0 ⌉   ⌈  1   0  0 ⌉
| -8   0  0 | = | -8  0  0 | x |  0   1  0 |
⌊ 91 715  1 ⌋   ⌊  0  0  1 ⌋   ⌊ 91 715  1 ⌋

  ⌈ 8 0 0 ⌉   ⌈  0  1  0 ⌉   ⌈  1   0  0 ⌉
= | 0 8 0 | x | -1  0  0 | x |  0   1  0 |
  ⌊ 0 0 1 ⌋   ⌊  0  0  1 ⌋   ⌊ 91 715  1 ⌋
```

> *How would a several transformations look like? For example Scaling and rotation*

We have such an example in the decomposition above,

```
⌈  0  8  0 ⌉   ⌈ 8 0 0 ⌉   ⌈  0  1  0 ⌉
| -8  0  0 | = | 0 8 0 | x | -1  0  0 |
⌊  0  0  1 ⌋   ⌊ 0 0 1 ⌋   ⌊  0  0  1 ⌋
```

a combination of a scaling by 8 and a rotation by 90°.

Comment: Thank you! I was pretty confused about this. I though that matrix has a scaling factor of 0, which makes no sense