# How to calculate text rotation angle in pdf

Tags: java, pdf

Please given the below stream and Tm matrix how can I calculate rotation angle for specific text??

/F1 1 Tf
0 -43.92 43.92 0 334.093 672.9771 Tm
0 g
0.0088 Tc
0.0877 Tw
(Fonts, Fonts, and more Fonts!)Tj

Comment: Angle relative to what? (Depending on your answer to that question you might also have to take the current transformation matrix and/or the rotation entry of the page into account.)

Comment: Furthermore look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354098/pdf-tm-operator).

Comment: I already have a transformation matrix specified above, my question how can get the angle by which text rotated from this matrix???

Comment: in the link you put how did you know this is a combination of a 90° rotation??

Comment: Look at the formulas quoted in the referenced question from the pdf specifications: *Rotation [cos(angle) sin(angle) -sin(angle) cos(angle) 0 0]*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the transformation matrix `T = [ a b c d e f ]` describes only rotation, scaling and
translation (but no skewing), then you can compute the rotation angle from the first two
components as

```
double angle = Math.atan2(b, a);
```

Note that `atan2()` returns the angle in radians. If you need the result in degrees, you have
to multiply it by `180.0/Math.PI`.

**ADDED:** As @mkl correctly said, if skewing is involved, the above formula gives the angle
by which the x-axis is rotated. (And the rotation of the y-axis can be computed as `atan2(-c, d)`).

Comment: *but no skewing* ... and if there is skewing involved, that atan2 at least returns the angle by which the x-axis is rotated.

Comment: @mkl: Thank you for the feedback, I have added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
Please given this matrix:
[7.73,2.07,-2.07,7.73,101.51,736.37] Tm
when I calculate Math.atan2(2.07,7.73) it returns 'NaN', what this??

Comment: @MohammedMostafa: `Math.atan2(2.07,7.73)` gives `0.26164883747339657` when I test it. Note that it should be `7.73`, not `7,73`.

Comment: Yes, this is my wrong, i modified the comment
I calculated it with another tool and get the same result you put
Thanks very much Martin for your good help